# Asymptotic expansion of $x\exp(1/x)=\exp(\lambda)$ as $\lambda\to\infty$

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I am struggling to find a three-term expansion of the following equation $x\exp(1/x)=\exp(\lambda)$ as $\lambda\to\infty$ for each of the solutions for $x$.
I graphed the functions $1/x$ and $\log(x)$ after taking the logarithm on both sides of the equation. I know, correct me if I am wrong, that for small root I get the $x\sim 1/\lambda$ balance, while for the large root the balance is $\log(x)\sim\lambda$.
Please guide me on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 5):

We first can solve the equation exactly as follows:
$$
xe^{1/x}=z\implies \frac{1}{x}e^{-1/x}=\frac{1}{z}\implies -\frac{1}{x}e^{-1/x}=-\frac{1}{z}.
$$
It follows that
$$
x=-\frac{1}{W_0(-1/z)}\ \text{or}\ x=-\frac{1}{W_{-1}(-1/z)},
$$
where $W_0(\cdot)$ is the principal branch of the Lambert $W$-function.  In your question you have $z=e^\lambda$, where $\lambda\to\infty$ and so we want the solution for $x$ in terms of $W_0(\cdot)$. As such, we can use the Taylor series for $W_0(\cdot)$ to obtain the desired asymptotic expansion.  First note
$$
W_0(s)=s\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-(n+1))^n}{(n+1)!}s^n.
$$
Using the formula for the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Multiplicative_inverse) of formal power series we write
$$
\frac{1}{W_0(s)}=\frac{1}{s}\left(1+s-\frac{1}{2}s^2+\mathcal O(s^3)\right).
$$
Substituting $s=-1/z$ we then obtain as $z\to\infty$:
$$
x=-\frac{1}{W_0(-1/z)}=z-1-\frac{1}{2z}+\mathcal O(z^{-2}).
$$
Substituting $z=e^\lambda$ then gives us the final asymptotic result for $\lambda\to\infty$:
$$
x\sim e^\lambda-1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda}.
$$

**Edit:**

If we want the second solution $x\ll 1$ then the asymptotic series for $z\to\infty$ can be derived using the same process as above and an [appropriate series expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/06/01/) for $W_{-1}(\cdot)$.

Comment: Thank you Aaron!
how could you use Lambert function when both x and lambda are real?  What about the asymptotic expansion when  x<<1?

Comment: @NC30 See edit.  You can follow the same process I did to get leading terms of asymptotic expansion for the $x\ll 1$ case.

Comment: What would we do without Lambert function ? Just by accident, I "discovered" it 60 years ago and I am still as fascinated as I was on the first day. Cheers :-)

Comment: @AaronHendrickson it is a bit vague to me, how did you obtain W0 Taylor's series. And how I suppose to get W-1 Taylor series?

Answer (score 3):

After @Aaron Hendrickson's answer, for the second branch
$$x=-\frac{1}{W_{-1}\left(-e^{-\lambda }\right)}$$ we could use the asymptotic expansion given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$W_{-1}(t)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=-\lambda$ and $L_2=\log(\lambda)$ to obtain
$${W_{-1}\left(-e^{-\lambda }\right)}=-\lambda -\log (\lambda )-\frac{\log (\lambda )}{\lambda }+\frac{(\log (\lambda )-2)
   \log (\lambda )}{2 \lambda ^2}-$$ $$\frac{\log (\lambda ) (2\log ^2(\lambda ) -9\log  (\lambda )+6)}{6 \lambda ^3}+\cdots$$ and then
$$x=\frac{1}{\lambda }-\frac{\log (\lambda )}{\lambda ^2}+\frac{\log
   (\lambda )(\log (\lambda )-1) }{\lambda ^3}-\frac{\log
   (\lambda )(2 \log ^2(\lambda )-5 \log (\lambda )+2) }{2\lambda ^4}+\cdots$$

or, more compact,
$$x=\frac 1 \lambda- \frac{\log (\lambda )}{2 \lambda ^4}\Big[2 \left(\lambda ^2+\lambda +1\right)-(2 \lambda -\log (\lambda )+5) \log (\lambda ) \Big]+\cdots$$ which is quite accurate.

Using $\lambda=5^k$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 0.147920235019603 & 0.144157704688610 \\
 2 & 0.035322286425834 & 0.035280299526838 \\
 3 & 0.007700440302570 & 0.007700214802757 \\
 4 & 0.001583662506572 & 0.001583661640015 \\
 5 & 0.000319177824945 & 0.000319177822221 \\
 6 & 0.000063960468364 & 0.000063960468356 \\
 7 & 0.000012798154410 & 0.000012798154410 
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We can improve the approximation making one single iteration of Newton method. This would give
$$x_1=\frac {x_0}{1-x_0} \left(1-e^{\lambda -\frac{1}{x_0}}\right)$$

Trying for $\lambda=5$

- $x_0=\frac 1 \lambda-\frac{\log (\lambda )}{\lambda ^2}=0.135622$ gives $x_1=0.142285$
- $x_0=\frac 1 \lambda-\frac{\log (\lambda )}{\lambda ^2}+\frac{\log
     (\lambda )(\log (\lambda )-1) }{\lambda ^3}=0.143469$ gives $x_1=0.1441445$

Comment: How did you obtain the expansion for W-1?

Comment: @NC30. Take the asymptotic expansion  given  in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function for $W_[-1}$ and just a bit of manipulation to get its reciprocal.

Comment: I cannot  get the expansion properly. could you please elaborate?

Comment: @NC30. Details added. Cheers :-)

Comment: I knew who posted this answer as soon as I saw the table of numeric values at the end! It's a dead giveaway ;)

Comment: @AaronHendrickson. For once, a quite nice formula with $W_{-1}(.)$. Cheers